# Selecting Date in Google Plus Profile using Python / Selenium-WebDriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I created a gmail account and then when to Google+. On landing page, it first asked me to complete profile like Gender / Month / Date

I observed that there is no Select Tag. It is a dynamic div and it uses active-

```
<div class="mxa MC">
<div aria-activedescendant=":1x" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="listbox" class="d-k-l d-y-r-c b-Qb hl">
<div aria-posinset="0" aria-setsize="4" role="option" id=":1x" class="d-k-l d-y-r-c-ha">Select</div>
<div aria-hidden="true" class="d-k-l d-y-r-c-Qa">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Am not able to understand how to click Male / Female once the dropdown list opens. The html doesn't change only the class expands further and aria-activedescendant value changes to :1q in case Male, :1r in case mouse hovers or Female

And on choosing this attribute value is set and next line "Select" text is changed to Male or Female, whichever chosen.

So how do select Gender or list items in such a situation

Flow was:

I created new Google Play Account through BlueStack, where it didn't ask for Gender / Month / Date

Then I opened browser on Desktop and opened this link
https://plus.google.com/up/accounts/upgrade/?continue=https://plus.google.com/

And there you get the option of Gender / Month / Date

Comment: Can you share that page link where you are filling birth date? Because i am trying to update birthdate and can see tags `Select - Options`.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/up/accounts/upgrade/?continue=https://plus.google.com/

Comment: Please note that I first created the account using Google Play inside Blue Stack, where Profile details are not taken. And after creation of account, I opened browser and opened this link https://plus.google.com/up/accounts/upgrade/?continue=https://plus.google.com/